# Non-native network interfaces

Tags: security

I have these strange non-native network interfaces popping up on my phone... and mind you, this is after factory resetting my phone 5 times in a row. Can anyone help me make sense of these?

Instead of a screenshot I'll just post the interfaces. They are:
v4-ccmni2
v4-ccmni0

Or is that the cellular network interface?

I logged onto wifi and then back off and got v4-ccmni2 when it was 0 before. Any clarification would be appreciated.